# .where query selector not working. Using sqlite3 and knex

Tags: sqlite

```
server.get('/api/projects/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const projectId = { id };
    db('projects').where(projectId).first()
    .then(project => {
        if(!project){
            res.status(404)
        }
    db('actions').where({'project_id' : projectId})
    .then(actions => {
        project.actions = actions
        res.json(project)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err.message)
    })
 });
```

Can anyone tell me why the .where query in db call to 'actions' is not working?

Comment: I have the id in projects set as a primary key.  The field project_id in actions is set as a foreign key

Comment: I figured it out.  It was because projectId is returning an object and the .where query needs a number there. I just made another variable equal to req.params.id